# Converting to Boolean Value in PHP

Tags: php

I think that asking this might be kind of silly but I'm still wondering whether there is built-in way to return false or true as they way they look instead of 0 or 1, well actually this code even doesn't write 0 but 1:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3);
echo (bool) $array;
?>
```

So I want this code to write "true" or "false" instead of numeric values. I know I can build a function but my curiosity likes to learn a built-in way if there is any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the [conditional operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
echo (true ? 'true' : 'false');
echo (false ? 'true' : 'false');
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/hNHhXnBv

Answer (score 5):

`echo`ing a boolean will always print either 0 or 1. Instead, use `var_dump()`.

Another option is to echo 'true' or 'false' based on the value:

```
echo ((bool)$array) ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Comment: what about to echo them actually and see?

Comment: so, does it *really* prints 0 and 1?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Light I am asking if PHP "always print either 0 or 1 when eching a boolean"

Comment: also, casting explicitly would be an overkill. `($array)` is enough.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: The answer is yes, and that's why the OP is here asking how to change that behaviour. Did you try it?

Comment: @Light the answer is no. echoing a boolean won't print 0 for false.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: No. It will echo nothing for false. True yields `1`. http://ideone.com/WpLc9

Comment: @Light well, I don't know what to say. Thank you for your effort in trying to enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

var_export() prints type and result.

```
echo var_export((bool)$array, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is to convert the array ELEMENTS to booleans, not the array as a whole.

You could use the function `array_map` for this.

```
function conv2bool($i) { return (bool) $i; }

$int_array = array(0,1,0,2,3);
$bool_array = array_map("conv2bool", $int_array);

var_dump($bool_array);
```

...this will return:

```
array(5) { [0]=> bool(false) [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(false) [3]=> bool(true) [4]=> bool(true) }
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? I've tried this code and it does exactly what I said.

Comment: your assumption, I believe. It's wrong.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense at all to convert a whole `array` to a single `boolean`?! This would just give you false if the array is empty and true otherwise, I suppose.

Comment: @MaxWeller: Yes, which makes perfect sense if that's what you want to do...